# Form WYSIWYG but stop user from breaking page layout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am looking into using a HTML WYSIWYG editor such as [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) but I am curious about what is to stop a user from submitting some HTML code that will change the layout of the page when I try to output their HTML.

Here is an example of two posts:

```
<p><b>This is my post</b></p>
<p>It has some nice HTML that does not break stuff</p>
```

and

```
</div>
<div style="height:10000px; width:10000px;">
    <p>muhahaha</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, the first post is nice and simple, I can display that and it wont look crazy. But the second post could alter my page layout completely (have not tested but you get the idea.

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='post'>
            <p><b>This is my post</b></p>
            <p>It has some nice HTML that does not break stuff</p>
        </div>
        <div class='post'>
            </div>
            <div style="height:10000px; width:10000px;">
                <p>muhahaha</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know I can use htmlentities but this would then display the first post without the bold and I do not want that.

The stackoverflow website must have something like this built in, and I am wondering if there is a simple way to stop users being able to submit layout-changing HTML via a WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: Editors like CKEditor have ability to prevent inline style and any other attributes being added. It is highly configurable. In case you are worried about someone bypassing the editor would need to use a server side dom parser to sanitize user input

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor has a feature called [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf) that in its default, automatic mode filters incoming HTML content by transforming and deleting disallowed elements, attributes, classes and styles. CKEditor will only allow content that was defined as allowed by enabled editor features (buttons, plugins).

It is highly configurable, too, so it lets you fully control what your users can and cannot submit to your website.

Have a look at the following resources to figure it out:

- [Content Filtering](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf)
- [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter)
- [Allowed Content Rules](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules)
- [Advanced Content Filter – Automatic Mode](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acf.html) sample
- [Advanced Content Filter – Custom Mode](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acfcustom.html) sample